# Verifying text-field entry and changing class for user feedback

Tags: javascript, dom

In [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/eG2Dm/14/), I have created a text-entry field that responds to the characters entered and appends a class to the parent `<div>` element for visual feedback based on whether the entry is expected, partial, or has an error.

In this case, the text field is for serial number entry; the field contents will eventually be sent to a dynamic table for building out an order.  Because of this, the serial number must have an absolute value in the prefix (i.e: ABCDE in the example) and contain exactly 14 characters... I'm having difficulty coming up with a working code that will turn the text box green if the prefix is correct and remain green regardless of the remaining 9 characters (although they do need to be strictly numeric and end in a letter).

Additionally, I have a feeling there is a shorter and more elegant way to implement the script for the prefix check.  Currently, I'm using:

```
if (el.value == "abcde" || el.value == "ABCDE") {
    document.getElementById('serial').className = 'serial-entry success';
} else if (el.value == "a" || el.value == "ab" || el.value == "abc" || el.value == "abcd" || el.value == "A" || el.value == "AB" || el.value == "ABC" || el.value == "ABCD") {
    document.getElementById('serial').className = 'serial-entry warning';
```

... where I know there's got to be a better way to write the expected ascending prefix values other than `(el.value == "a" || el.value == "ab" ||...` and so on.  Using my current method, I would need to write half-a-billion variants of the `el.value` in order to satisfy all combinations.

Please be aware that I am not versed in JS; everything I know I've picked up from this site. It's the equivalent of moving to a foreign country and learning the language solely by eavesdropping on conversation - my grammar, syntax, and vocabulary are sparse, at best. In other words: feel free to humiliate me with sage-like wisdom.

**--- EDIT: Answered! ---**

Thanks to Felix Kling for the solution.  I should have been more clear on where the state changes would occur, so I'll do so now and then include the code.

Rules:

1.) As the user enters the first letters of the prefix in correct order ("abcde"), the class of the text box should change to let the user know that they're on the right track, but not quite finished (partial).
2.) If the prefix is entered exact and we're agnostic of the following numbers ("123456789"), but they eventually do enter the correct prefix and a total of 14 characters, then the state (class) of the text box should toggle showing a success indicator.
3.) All other entries into the text box should be considered as erroneous, and an error class should be appended respectively.
4.) Lastly, if the user clears the text box of any string they entered, then the box should revert its class to the original state and not persist with any of the above classes.

[Here is Felix's revised jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eG2Dm/24/).

And purely the JS:

```
    function checkSerial(el) {
var value = el.value.toLowerCase();
var prefix = 'abcde';
var className = 'error'; // assume no match

if (!value) {
    className = '';
}
else if (value.length === 14 &&
         value.indexOf(prefix) === 0) { // match
    className = 'success';
}
else if ((value.length >= prefix.length &&
         value.indexOf(prefix) === 0) || // match
         prefix.indexOf(value) === 0) { // partial match
    className = 'warning';
}

document.getElementById('serial').className = 'serial-entry ' + className;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and test that the string starts with the prefix:

```
document.getElementById('serial').className = 
    el.value.toLowerCase().indexOf('abcde') === 0 ? 
    'serial-entry success' : 
    'serial-entry warning';
```

For the three case, match, partial match, no match, you can check whether the input string is shorter than the prefix and apply the same logic, but vice versa:

```
var value = el.value.toLowerCase();
var prefix = 'abcde';
var className = 'error'; // assume no match

if (value.length >= prefix.length) {
    if (value.indexOf(prefix) === 0) { // match
        className = 'success';
    }
}
else if (prefix.indexOf(value) === 0) { // partial match
    className = 'warning'
}

document.getElementById('serial').className = 'serial-entry ' + className;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eG2Dm/18/)

Comment: This gives me close to the behavior I'm after, but I'm still missing the third feedback option - `'serial-entry error'` - which should turn the text box red if the prefix does not match any part of the string "abcde"... using the above method, I can't seem to properly add `if` and `else if` statements to make that piece work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Should have been a little more clear on when the states should change.  With a little adjustment to your code, I have [the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/eG2Dm/19/) I was hoping for.  Major thanks!  Will update question.

Comment: Yep that works as well. I'd still move the assignment to `document.getElementById('serial').className` at the end of the `if...else if` block. You don't have to repeat the assignment three times. Imagine you change the ID of the element, then you have to change it at three locations instead of one. Just an advice. Happy coding!

Comment: Hrm, if I do that, I can't get step 2 to resolve... I lose the className value after the prefix is entered correctly. [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/eG2Dm/21/)

Comment: Still dropping appended class after successful prefix and before final character for me...

Comment: I see. Here is an implementation based on my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/eG2Dm/24/.

Answer (score 0):

suggesting to use `RegEx` to match the prefix as follows:

```
var val = el.value;
if(val.match(/\bABCDE/g)!=null) {
     document.getElementById('serial').className = "serial-entry success";
} else {
  document.getElementById('serial').className = "serial-entry error";
}
```

this way you can easily validate if the input is starting exactly with 'ABCDE'.
You can change the `RegEx` to suite your requirements.

Comment: This doesn't take care of partial matches.

Comment: can have another RegEx for partrial matching... suggesting a good approach actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

if(el.value.toLowerCase().indexOf('abcde') == 0 && el.value.length == 14)
      document.getElementById('serial').className = "serial-entry success";

else

document.getElementById('serial').className = "serial-entry warning";

Comment: Similar to my comments above, I can't seem to get the `serial-entry error` class to append if I use this method.  Example:

Comment: Timed out on my edit.... Here's the [updated jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eG2Dm/17/).  While typing a,b,c, and d, it's red... when, as given by your example as well as Felix Kling's, it should be orange.  It should only become red if 'a' is no the first character, 'b' is not the second, and so on until 'e.'